# Error with on click listener

Tags: android, onclick

```
    sadButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
                Intent response = new Intent(MainActivity.this, UserResponse.class);
                startActivity(response);
            }
        }
```

error:
setonClickListener (cannot resolve symbol), cannot resolve symbol v

I tried this code before and it worked without any error. So what's wrong here?

Comment: Post your Logcat and also make sure `sadButton` is actually a button.

Comment: Are you really using `setonClickListener` somewhere?

Comment: Provide proper information

Answer (score 0):

```
just add ); in the end like this


sadButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
                Intent response = new Intent(MainActivity.this,UserResponse.class);
                startActivity(response);
            }
        });
```